# React-beautiful-dnd unexpected token error in package file

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I was trying to compile a react program, which includes react-beautiful-dnd. However, I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (path)\node_modules\react-beautiful-dnd\src\state\auto-scroller\can-scroll.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (2:14)

  1 | // @flow
> 2 | import { type Position } from 'css-box-model';
    |               ^
  3 | import { add, apply, isEqual, origin } from '../position';
  4 | import type { DroppableDimension, Viewport, Scrollable } from '../../types';
  5 |
```

This file is part of the dependency, and it was working perfectly fine until about 30 minutes ago. I have tried reinstalling the package and the error still shows up.

Comment: What's your react-beautiful-dnd version?

Comment: @AjeetShah I solved the problem. My IDE auto-imported something which i guess broke the program somehow. Thank you for responding anyway.